# Зашёл в тупик с for statement в пакетных файлах

Tags: файлы, cmd

Нужно написать программу,которая будет сначала считывать переменные, потом их выведет. На Linux более менее сделал, но вот на батниках не могу понять как.

Comment: Ну так покажи код для линукса, чтобы было понятно, что ты вообще делаешь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set /P var1=Enter var1:
echo %var1%
```

**Update**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :input_vars v1 v2 v3 v4

for %%A in (v1 v2 v3 v4) do (
    echo %%A = !%%A!
)

endlocal
exit /b 0

:input_vars
for %%A in (%*) do (
    set /p %%A=Enter %%A:
)
exit /b 0
```

Comment: Да, но тут я могу вести только одну переменную. Мне надо чтобы я мог вводить неопределённое количество переменных и программа их выводила

Comment: Не понятно. Нужен пример: что вводим, какие переменные получаем, что выводим.

Comment: Вводим любые числа, выводим эти же самые. Закончить ввод можно значением -1

Comment: А храниться они в чем будут? Сколько переменных надо? Под каждое число или всего одну?

Comment: Вот именно, не знаю как. На линуксе уже написал такую программу, вроде работает. Да, под каждую одну
#!/bin/sh
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$var"
done

Comment: Обновил ответ .